# Typing the Pinyin third tone accent for character that denotes "woman"

Tags: symbols

Who knows how to type 女 in Pinyin, utilizing a LaTeX command?  That is curve tone and the two dots.

Comment: You can use a Unicode-aware engine (LuaTeX/XeTeX) or do `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and type the character directly into the source. Of course, the character must be present in your chosen font.

Answer (score 3):

Am I assuming correctly that you want to type the character ǚ?

One good way to do this is the [`tipa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) package; then, `\textipa{\v{\"{u}}}` yields ǚ.

Comment: Shouldn't the third-tone "accent" be a more rounded than what's produced by `\v` ("vee-check")?

Comment: No @Mico. Third tone uses a caron, which is `\v`. "More rounded" is the breve. Cfr [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron).

Comment: @MickG - Thanks for setting the record straight. I guess my Mandarin teacher consistently used the wrong accent character!

Answer (score 3):

You should search for a font which supports these accented letters. In the following, I use Linux Libertine loaded with `fontspec` (which requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX):

```
% arara: xelatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{cl}\toprule
            Vowels & Tones\\\midrule
            a & \=a \'a \v a \`a$\cdot$a\\
            e & \=e \'e \v e \`e$\cdot$e\\
            i & \=i \'i \v i \`i$\cdot$i\\
            o & \=o \'o \v o \`o$\cdot$o\\
            u & \=u \'u \v u \`u$\cdot$u\\
            ü & \=ü \'ü \v ü \`ü$\cdot$ü\\\bottomrule       
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

All these letters do have their own unicode as well. For the ü-letters this would be [U+01D6](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d6/index.htm), [U+01D8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d8/index.htm), [U+01DA](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1da/index.htm), and [U+01DC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1dc/index.htm).

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}        
    \symbol{"01D6}\symbol{"01D8}\symbol{"01DA}\symbol{"01DC}$\cdot$ü
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I like to define

```
%tones of chinese pinin
\usepackage{tipa}
\newcommand{\1}[1]{\textipa{\={#1}}}
\newcommand{\2}[1]{\textipa{\'{#1}}}
\newcommand{\3}[1]{\textipa{\v{#1}}}
\newcommand{\4}[1]{\textipa{\`{#1}}}
```

Then just do

```
\3{ü}
```